# Clicking columns in a table

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table, mouseevent

I am building a website that loads a table. I have loaded a table from my database and displayed it in a table on the webpage. Now I want to be able to click on specific columns in the table. Once clicked I want the selected column(s) to be highlighted, after being highlighted I want a button that saves all the clicked columns to a record in a database?

I am not sure how to do this as I am fairly new to coding in Html/Javascript/php.

So if I click row1 cell1 and then row2cell2 I want both of them to highlight and then I want to click a submit button that then saves the data in those cells to a record in my database.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFun(e){
      if(!e.target) alert(e.srcElement.innerHTML);
      else alert(e.target.innerHTML); }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table id="tableID" onclick="myFun(event)" border="1">
<tr>
 <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
 <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
 <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am guessing I will need mousevents but thats all I am sure of please help?

Comment: My first take is to use the onclick="" event on the table cells for the header, and then making the ids of all of the cells below equal to an array with that header's name, like id="cities[]".  Then, with Javascript, you could change the background color of all of the items in the array when the onclick event is fired.  Let's see some code

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:nth-child()` selector, e.g third column:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJaFa/)

```
$('table').find('tr :nth-child(3)').on('click', function(){
    alert('Third column clicked!');
});
```

You could exclude the header cell:

```
$('table').find('tr :nth-child(3):not(th)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way of doing it it's by creating a new field in the database and assigning a value to the column that when selected update the database. Once it's read you can highlighted by simply changing the CSS. Use Javascript to make it change on the client side so you don't have to be reloading the page all the time.